# If f is an $L^p$ function and $\int f(x)g(x)dx=0$ for every $L^p$ function g does that imply that f=0 a.e

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

If $f$ is an $L^p$ function and $\int f(x)g(x)dx=0$ for every $L^p$
 function $g$ does that imply that $f=0$ a.e

Comment: What if $g=f$?${}$

Comment: the integral is zero on an integral (say [a,b]) for every $L^p$ function g. The case f=g is not arbitrary

Comment: I meant to suggest that with your hypotheses, you'd have $\int f^2=0$.

Comment: yes but if I am not mistaken what you are saying implies f=0 a.e

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it implies that $f=0$ a.e. For if we let $g=f$, then we have $$\int f^2=0,$$ and $f^2\geq0$. This implies that $f^2=0$ a.e., hence $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: oh I see. thank you very much both of you